# Excluding a single category from Wordpress all posts results

Tags: wordpress, categories

I'm looking for a bit of help as I struggle to create a page that has a list of all of my clients' products.  Currently I'm using this URL, which works great (with a caveat): http://tayloryourevent.com/?p=*

(note: on her site, both products and blogs are created as posts, but in separate categories)

As you can see, all the products show up nicely, but also included in the mix are blog posts, which I need to hide from that page.

My real problem is that I'm confused by the /?p=* and what that's doing.  Since it's a page being created on the fly, I don't know where to look to get a glimpse behind the scenes.

2 questions:

1. Where is the /?p=* getting its theme from?  Could I copy that theme and edit it to exclude the blog category?
   -or-
2. Could I exclude the blog category with some kind of fancy URL work?

Answer (score 0):

This plugin should be able to exclude blog categories: [Simply Exclude](http://wordpress.org/plugins/simply-exclude/)

Comment: I tried using Simply Exclude, but it only had options to exclude from the front page (which in my case is static) or the archives (which I don't use).

I'm wondering if the /?p=* code in the URL is the problem?

Comment: If the /?p=* is the problem, you would want to change it. Generally you always want to change the p to something better. This helps search engines, users, and plugins. To change this, go to Dashboard>Settings>Permalinks. Most people change it from the Default to the post name setting. Try this and see if it works.